# Android Html.fromHtml takes too long

Tags: android

What do I do if `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));` takes too long, and hangs the UI?
If I can do it with a thread, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
     void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          switch(msg.what) {
               case UPDATE_TEXT_VIEW:
                    tv.setText(msg.obj); // set text with Message data
                    break;
          }
     }
}

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     // use handler to send message to run on UI thread.
     mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(UPDATE_TEXT_VIEW, Html.fromHtml(text));
});
t.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to parse long or complex HTML, manual composing of `Spannable` is much faster than using `Html.fromHtml()`. Following sample comes from [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```