# Set color of TextView span in Android

Tags: android, text, formatting, textview

Is it possible to set the color of just span of text in a TextView?

I would like to do something similar to the Twitter app, in which a part of the text is blue. See image below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://g.twimg.com/blog/s1600/ss-localsearch.png))</sub>

Answer (score 499, accepted):

Another answer would be very similar, but wouldn't need to set the text of the `TextView` twice

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: but how can i change the color for multiple words i all text not one span?

Comment: @mostafahashim create multiple spans by repeating line 3 wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 50, 80, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: Kotlin + Spannable String solution would look like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview/59510004#59510004

Answer (score 94):

Here is a little help function. Great for when you have multiple languages!

```
private void setColor(TextView view, String fulltext, String subtext, int color) {
    view.setText(fulltext, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable str = (Spannable) view.getText();
    int i = fulltext.indexOf(subtext);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), i, i + subtext.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Answer (score 54):

I always find visual examples helpful when trying to understand a new concept.

## Background Color

[image]

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World!");
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
spannableString.setSpan(backgroundSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

## Foreground Color

[image]

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World!");
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

## Combination

[image]

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Hello World!");
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
BackgroundColorSpan backgroundSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
spannableString.setSpan(foregroundSpan, 0, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannableString.setSpan(backgroundSpan, 3, spannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

## Further Study

- [Explain the meaning of Span flags like SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949135/3681880)
- [Android Spanned, SpannedString, Spannable, SpannableString and CharSequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935087/3681880)

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon, That sounds like custom painting and not a simple background color. Check out Bezier curves.

Comment: Have you any good references or resources to about it? I need to add a curvey background of my notification action button. Thanks for your response

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon, sorry I don't. It's been a while since I've done custom painting in Android since I moved on to Flutter.

Answer (score 33):

If you want more control, you might want to check the `TextPaint` class. Here is how to use it:

```
final ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View textView) {
        //Your onClick code here
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(final TextPaint textPaint) {
        textPaint.setColor(yourContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        textPaint.setUnderlineText(true);
    }
};
```

Comment: getColor(int id) is deprecated on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23

Comment: Nice Answer With Click Listener.

Answer (score 23):

Set your `TextView`´s text spannable and define a `ForegroundColorSpan` for your text.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);    
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");          
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
textView.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this without assigning the text to the TextView first?

Comment: I didn't explain myself well. Let me rephrase. Are the first 3 lines necessary? Can't you create the Spannable object from the string directly?

Comment: Nop, you have to store your TextView's text into a Buffer Spannable to change the foreground colour.

Comment: I want to to the same thing with the color plus I want everything to be bold except the colored part, that part I want to be Italic , how can I do that ?

Comment: how to set click in the span?

Answer (score 15):

Another way that could be used in some situations is to set the link color in the properties of the view that is taking the Spannable.

If your Spannable is going to be used in a TextView, for example, you can set the link color in the XML like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorLink="@color/your_color"
</TextView>
```

You can also set it in the code with:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setLinkTextColor(your_color);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
String text = "I don't like Hasina.";
textView.setText(spannableString(text, 8, 14));

private SpannableString spannableString(String text, int start, int end) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    ColorStateList redColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{0xffa10901});
    TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, redColor, null);

    spannableString.setSpan(highlightSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFCFF48), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    return spannableString;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Here's a Kotlin Extension Function I have for this

```
    fun TextView.setColouredSpan(word: String, color: Int) {
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)
        val start = text.indexOf(word)
        val end = text.indexOf(word) + word.length
        try {
            spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            text = spannableString
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
         println("'$word' was not not found in TextView text")
    }
}
```

Use it after you have set your text to the TextView like so

```
private val blueberry by lazy { getColor(R.color.blueberry) }

textViewTip.setColouredSpan("Warning", blueberry)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much buddy you make my day :*

Comment: Should be the best answer for Kotlin implementation.

Comment: Amazing implementation

Comment: You can simplify by writing: `val end = start + word.length`.

Answer (score 8):

**Set Color** on **Text** by **passing String** and **color**:

```
private String getColoredSpanned(String text, String color) {
  String input = "<font color=" + color + ">" + text + "</font>";
  return input;
}
```

**Set text** on **TextView / Button / EditText** etc by calling below code:

**TextView:**

```
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
```

**Get Colored String:**

```
String name = getColoredSpanned("Hiren", "#800000");
```

**Set Text on TextView:**

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(name));
```

**Done**

Answer (score 8):

[image: Textview Span]

Using kotlin-ktx, you can achieve it easily

```
        bindView?.oneTimePasswordTitle?.text = buildSpannedString {
        append("One Time Password ")
        inSpans(
            ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(bindView?.oneTimePasswordTitle?.context!!,R.color.colorPrimaryText))
        ){
            append(" (As Registered Email)")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a factory for creating the Spannable, and avoid the cast, like this:

```
Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("text");
```

Comment: Could you clarify how to use SpannableFactory? How "text" should look like?

Comment: after creating the Spannable by the SpannableFactory, so how to use it?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the accepted answer, as all the answers seem to talk about [`android.graphics.Color`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color) only: what if the color I want is defined in `res/values/colors.xml`?

For example, consider [Material Design colors](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html) defined in `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="md_blue_500">#2196F3</color>
</resources>
```

([`android_material_design_colours.xml`](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/b0b8cfa773488e138037) is your best friend)

Then use `ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.md_blue_500)` where you would use `Color.BLUE`, so that:

```
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

becomes:

```
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.md_blue_500)), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Where I found that:

- [Working with spans in Android – Michael Spitsin – Medium](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/working-with-spans-in-android-ca4ab1327bc4)

Answer (score 3):

Some answers here aren't up to date. Because, **you will (in most of cases) add a custom clic action on your link**.

Besides, as provided by the documentation help, your spanned string link color will have a default one. 
*"The default link color is the theme's accent color or android:textColorLink if this attribute is defined in the theme".*

Here is the way to do it safely.

```
 private class CustomClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    private int color = -1;

    public CustomClickableSpan(){
        super();
        if(getContext() != null) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setColor(color != -1 ? color : ds.linkColor);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
    }
}
```

Then to use it.

```
   String text = "my text with action";
    hideText= new SpannableString(text);
    hideText.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
            // your action here !
        }

    }, 0, text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    yourtextview.setText(hideText);
    // don't forget this ! or this will not work !
    yourtextview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this will strongly help !

Answer (score 1):

1. create textview in ur layout
2. paste this code in ur MainActivity

   ```
   TextView textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
   Spannable spannable=new SpannableString("Hello my name is sunil");
   spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 5, 
   Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   textview.setText(spannable);
   //Note:- the 0,5 is the size of colour which u want to give the strring
   //0,5 means it give colour to starting from h and ending with space i.e.(hello), if you want to change size and colour u can easily
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Below works perfectly for me

```
    tvPrivacyPolicy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrivacyPolicy);
    String originalText = (String)tvPrivacyPolicy.getText();
    int startPosition = 15;
    int endPosition = 31;

    SpannableString spannableStr = new SpannableString(originalText);
    UnderlineSpan underlineSpan = new UnderlineSpan();
    spannableStr.setSpan(underlineSpan, startPosition, endPosition, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ForegroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
    spannableStr.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, startPosition, endPosition, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    StyleSpan styleSpanItalic  = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

    spannableStr.setSpan(styleSpanItalic, startPosition, endPosition, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    tvPrivacyPolicy.setText(spannableStr);
```

> Output for above code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension function in Kotlin

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.colorizeText(
    textPartToColorize: CharSequence,
    @ColorInt color: Int
): CharSequence = SpannableString(this).apply {
    val startIndexOfText = this.indexOf(textPartToColorize.toString())
    setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), startIndexOfText, startIndexOfText.plus(textPartToColorize.length), 0)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val colorizedText = "this text will be colorized"
val myTextToColorize = "some text, $colorizedText continue normal text".colorizeText(colorizedText,ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.someColor))
viewBinding.myTextView.text = myTextToColorize
```

Answer (score 1):

- I got the same issue.
- @Dano's answer is absolutely correct. But it doesn't work for me.
- After that, I found the issue I have added ClickableSpan. So it will change my color with another color (accent color)

### Issue

---

SpannableStringBuilder will not change color and undline when you add a **ClickableSpan** after **ForegroundColorSpan** or **UnderlineSpan**.

### Solution

---

**1. With ClickableSpan**

- You can Override the **updateDrawState** method inside **ClickableSpan**.
- In the updateDrawState method, you should remove the super callback.
- After that, you should Modify your text paint as required.
  [image]

**2. Without ClickableSpan**

- Add ForegroundColorSpan to change the text color
- Add UnderlineSpan to add underline in text.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

From the developer docs, to change the color and size of a spannable:

1- create a class:

```
    class RelativeSizeColorSpan(size: Float,@ColorInt private val color: Int): RelativeSizeSpan(size) {

    override fun updateDrawState(textPaint: TextPaint?) {
        super.updateDrawState(textPaint)
        textPaint?.color = color
    } 
}
```

2 Create your spannable using that class:

```
    val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(titleNames)
spannable.setSpan(
    RelativeSizeColorSpan(1.5f, Color.CYAN), // Increase size by 50%
    titleNames.length - microbe.name.length, // start
    titleNames.length, // end
    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the CodeView library to highlight patterns with different colors easily, for example, to highlight all URLs inside the text with the blue color you just need to write

```java
CodeView codeView = findViewById(R.id.codeview);
codeView.addSyntaxPattern(Patterns.WEB_URL, Color.BLUE);
codeView.setTextHighlighted(text);
```

CodeView Repository URL: https://github.com/amrdeveloper/codeview

Answer (score -1):

```
First Part **Second Part should be Bold** last Part
```

This text should be changed using SpannableString

```
import android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD
import android.text.Spannable
import android.text.Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
import android.text.SpannableString
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan
import android.text.style.StyleSpan

val firstPart = "First Part  "
val secondPart = "Second Part should be Bold"
val thirdPart = "  last Part"
val finalString = firstPart + secondPart + thirdPart

val sb: Spannable = SpannableString(finalString).also {
                // ... Change text Colour
                it.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pink)),
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart),
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart) + secondPart.length,
                    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                // ... Make the text Bold
                it.setSpan(
                    StyleSpan(BOLD),
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart),
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart) + secondPart.length,
                    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                // ... Change Background Colour
                it.setSpan(
                    BackgroundColorSpan(getColor(requireContext(), R.color.lightPink)),
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart) - 1,
                    finalString.indexOf(secondPart) + secondPart.length + 1,
                    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
}

yourTextView.text = sb
```