# Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?

Tags: android, textview

I am looking to change the text of a TextView view via the .setText("") method while also coloring a part of the text (or making it bold, italic, transparent, etc.)and not the rest. For example:

```
title.setText("Your big island <b>ADVENTURE!</b>";
```

I know the above code is incorrect but it helps illustrate what I would like to achieve. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I change color part of a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-color-part-of-a-textview)

Comment: If there is a long text in the TextView,There is [a more efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34449956/3414180)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set color of TextView span in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Comment: Solution in Kotlin using Spans https://stackoverflow.com/a/59510004/11166067

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use [spans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html).

Example:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");

// Span to set text color to some RGB value
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

// Span to make text bold
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

// Set the text color for first 4 characters
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

// make them also bold
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: I really do't like the solution android offers here, as it does not work with multi language as I have no idea how many chars in my words are. I'm currently looking for a solution where I can have multiple spans that I can attach all to a TextView and then they are put together

Comment: The comment saying span to make text bold, should it say span to make text color?

Comment: @philipp if your problem is how many characters in your word, use the length() method on your String or StringBuilder or whatever

Comment: If there is a long text in the TextView, here is [a more efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34449956/3414180)

Comment: I initially missed this when reading the answer, but your end index has to be +1 the ending index in the string (i.e. to span first four letters you have to set [start, end] as [0, 4] not [0, 3] )

Comment: Why do you declare the first three variables as `final`?

Comment: Don't pay attention to it. I declare final any variable that is not supposed to change during method invocation

Answer (score 47):

```
title.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your big island <b>ADVENTURE!</b>"));
```

Comment: This is a far nicer solution to the original problem than the marked answer is.

Comment: If you have line breaks \n, this doesn't display the line breaks.

Comment: No, it is not nicer, there is no coloring feature, mentioned in question but SLOW method fromHTML()

Comment: So using `<font color="#FFAADD>text</font>` won't work?

Comment: @milosmns yes it does not work on all version specially older one. This is not the safest solution

Answer (score 26):

I hope this helps you (it works with multi language).

```
<string name="test_string" ><![CDATA[<font color="%1$s"><b>Test/b></font>]]> String</string>
```

And on your java code, you can do:

```
int color = context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
String string = context.getString(R.string.test_string, color);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(string));
```

This way, only the "Test" part will be colored (and bold).

Comment: Best Answer.  This works perfectly for internationalized strings.  Also has the advantage of being able to have your colored text in the middle of your string resource.

Comment: For further explanations see the **Styling with HTML markup** section [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Comment: What makes the CDATA thing necessary?

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Kotlin you can do the following using the [android-ktx](https://github.com/android/android-ktx) library

```
val title = SpannableStringBuilder()
        .append("Your big island ")
        .bold { append("ADVENTURE") } 

titleTextField.text = title
```

The `bold` is an extension function on `SpannableStringBuilder`. You can see the documentation [here](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.text/android.text.-spannable-string-builder/index.html) for a list of operations you can use.

Another example:

```
val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder()
            .color(green) { append("Green text ") }
            .append("Normal text ")
            .scale(0.5F) { append("Text at half size ") }
            .backgroundColor(green) { append("Background green") }
```

Where `green` is a resolved RGB color.

It is even possible to nest spans so you end up with something like an embedded DSL:

```
bold { underline { italic { append("Bold and underlined") } } }
```

You will need the following in your app module level `build.gradle` for it to work:

```
repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'
}
```

Comment: Also, no matter which color I put it, it shows same purple color.

`val spannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
spannableStringBuilder.bold { underline { color(R.color.test_color) { append(underlinedText) } } }`

Answer (score 17):

Here's an example that will look for all occurrences of a word (case insensitive), and color them red:

```
String notes = "aaa AAA xAaax abc aaA xxx";
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(notes);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aaa", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(notes);
while (m.find()){
    //String word = m.group();
    //String word1 = notes.substring(m.start(), m.end());

    sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)), m.start(), m.end(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
}
editText.setText(sb);
```

Comment: i love your name :P Can i change the background of specific word with new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#BFFFC6")) ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a `Spannable` to give certain parts of a text certain aspects. I can look up an example if you want.

Ah, from right here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android).

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01); 
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: How can we configure start and end range for multi language text?

Comment: One idea could be to identify the word that you need to highlight and extract it as a separate string resource. When translating the phrase you will need to consider update the separate word also so that when you set the span to rely on the indexOf the string and string length to dynamically set the start and end indexes of the span.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use HTML, you need to use `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String htmlString))`

If you want to do that often / repeatedly, you may have a look at a class ([SpannableBuilder](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/helper/SpannableBuilder.java)) I wrote, as `Html.fromHtml()` is not very efficient (it is using a big xml parsing machinery inside). It is described in this [blog posting](http://javablogs.com/Jump.action?id=618026).

Answer (score 4):

```html
            String str1 = "If I forget my promise to ";
            String penalty = "Eat breakfast every morning,";
            String str2 = " then I ";
            String promise = "lose my favorite toy";
           

            String strb = "<u><b><font color='#081137'>"+ penalty +",</font></b></u>";
            String strc = "<u><b><font color='#081137'>"+ promise + "</font></b></u>";
            String strd = str1 +strb+ str2 + strc;
           tv_notification.setText(Html.fromHtml(strd));
```

or use this code:

```html
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            SpannableString text1 = new SpannableString(str1);
            text1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver)), 0, str1.length() - 1, 0);
            builder.append(text1);

            SpannableString text2 = new SpannableString(penalty);
            text2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.midnight)), 0, penalty.length(), 0);
            text2.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, penalty.length(), 0);
            builder.append(text2);

            SpannableString text3 = new SpannableString(str2);
            text3.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver)),0, str2.length(), 0);
            builder.append(text3);


            SpannableString text4 = new SpannableString(promise);
            text4.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.midnight)), 0, promise.length(), 0);
            text4.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),0, promise.length(), 0);
            builder.append(text4);

          tv_notification.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void setColorForPath(Spannable spannable, String[] paths, int color) {
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        int indexOfPath = spannable.toString().indexOf(paths[i]);
        if (indexOfPath == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), indexOfPath,
                indexOfPath + paths[i].length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Using

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("Your big island ADVENTURE");
Utils.setColorForPath(spannable, new String[] { "big", "ADVENTURE" }, Color.BLUE);

textView.setText(spannable);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `SpannableStringBuilder` by appending the different spans one by one, rather than calling setSpan by calculating the string lengths

as: *(Kotlin code)*

```
val amountSpannableString = SpannableString("₹$amount").apply {
  // text color
  setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan("#FD0025".parseColor()), 0, length, 0)
  // text size
  setSpan(AbsoluteSizeSpan(AMOUNT_SIZE_IN_SP.spToPx(context)), 0, length, 0)
  // font medium
  setSpan(TypefaceSpan(context.getString(R.string.font_roboto_medium)), 0, length, 0)
}

val spannable: Spannable = SpannableStringBuilder().apply {
  // append the different spans one by one
  // rather than calling setSpan by calculating the string lengths
  append(TEXT_BEFORE_AMOUNT)
  append(amountSpannableString)
  append(TEXT_AFTER_AMOUNT)
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate two or more Spans. This way is easier to color dynamic text using length value.

```
SpannableStringBuilder span1 = new SpannableStringBuilder("Android");
ForegroundColorSpan color1=new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
span1.setSpan(color1, 0, span1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

SpannableStringBuilder span2 = new SpannableStringBuilder("Love");
ForegroundColorSpan color2=new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSecondary));
span2.setSpan(color2, 0, span2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

Spanned concatenated=(Spanned) TextUtils.concat(span1," => ",span2);

SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder(concatenated);

TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_texview);
tv.setText(result, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use this code its helpful**

```
TextView txtTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
txtTest.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is <font color="#ff4343">Red</font> Color!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension function in Kotlin

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.colorizeText(
    textPartToColorize: CharSequence,
    @ColorInt color: Int
): CharSequence = SpannableString(this).apply {
    val startIndexOfText = this.indexOf(textPartToColorize.toString())
    setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color), startIndexOfText, startIndexOfText.plus(textPartToColorize.length), 0)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val colorizedText = "this text will be colorized"
val myTextToColorize = "some text, $colorizedText continue normal text".colorizeText(colorizedText,ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.someColor))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Html.fromHtml` is **deprecated**

Use [HtmlCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat) instead

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to get in trouble on lower SDK version use `SpannableStringBuilder` with `ForegroundColorSpan` or `BackgroundColorSpan` as `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` color style does not applied on older Android version.