# ActionBar text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-text-color

how can I change the text color of the ActionBar? I've inherited the Holo Light Theme, I'm able to change the background of the ActionBar but I don't find out what is the attribute to tweak to change the text color.

---

Ok, I'm able to change the text color with the attribute android:textColorPrimary but it also changes the text color of the dropdown menu displayed when an overflow happen on the ActionBar buttons. Any idea how to change the color of those dropdown menu / List ?

Comment: just posted a solution that worked for me.  see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16175220/627827

Answer (score 459):

Ok, I've found a better way. I'm now able to only change the color of the title. You can also tweak the subtitle.

**Here is my styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is the correct way. However, for consistency, you should be inheriting from `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` for `MyTheme.ActionBarStyle`.

Comment: How do you change the background colour in addition to the text? I want the holo light theme with a black background action bar with white text and the blue underline as well...

Comment: Won't build - ADT complains that it requires v13 or above (so ... won't work on most Android handsets :( )

Comment: How to inherit for ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: @Adam I had the same problem, but the next answer works for me -- instead of parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title" use  parent="@android:style/TextAppearance"

Comment: If you are using Appcompat library, replace Holo with AppCompat. It works

Comment: @LOG_TAG Use Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar

Comment: Is it possible to change it programatically?

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Only change the action bar colour. Instead of changing the text colour.

Comment: @sha, correct ! Just to be precise, use "@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" and not "@android:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"

Comment: for those who are saying that they were unable to get it working in appcompat. here is the correct way to do it. http://prnt.sc/eosf3y

Comment: Finally worked after setting name="titleTextStyle" instead of name="android:titleTextStyle" in MyTheme.ActionBarStyle

Answer (score 103):

I found a way that works well with any flavor of `ActionBar` (*Sherlock*, *Compat*, and *Native*):

Just use *html* to set the title, and specify the text color. For example, to set the *ActionBar* text color to red, simply do this:

```
getActionBar()/* or getSupportActionBar() */.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
```

You can also use the red hex code `#FF0000` instead of the word `red`. If you are having trouble with this, see [Android Html.fromHtml(String) doesn't work for <font color='#'>text</font>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400619/android-html-fromhtmlstring-doesnt-work-for-font-color-text-font).

---

Additionally, if you want to use a color resource, this code can be used to get the correct HEX String, and removing the alpha if needed (the *font* tag does not support alpha):

```
int orange = getResources().getColor(R.color.orange);
String htmlColor = String.format(Locale.US, "#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & Color.argb(0, Color.red(orange), Color.green(orange), Color.blue(orange))));
```

Comment: This gives an error because you have to put a string in the method Html.fromHtml(), and you are placing multiple parameters in the method. When replacing the "," by "+" this works perfectly :-).

Comment: @pinyin_samu, thanks for the catch! I had removed a `buildString` method that uses comma-separated Objects, and overlooked this. It is now fixed.

Comment: After decades of searching, this is the easiest solution! Great job!

Comment: Most important thing; it works all the way down to Android API level 9! Awesome!

Comment: What if I don't have the color name, rather color code stored in a string? e.g. dynamically I received color code #004911 and stored in 'color' string and now trying to change the title color?

Comment: @MSI, you can use hex values too, just replace `red` with `" + color + "`.

Comment: @Phil : I tried in this way actually, doesn't work. Like my color string holds the code gree, here color = "#004911". I am applyng in this way: getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"+ color +\">" + getString(R.string.menu) + "</font>"));  I am using v7-appcompat library. My title changes, but the color doesn't.

Comment: In addition, could you please also tell how to change the color of back navigation arrow in the actionbar?

Comment: @MSI, can you try what [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400619/android-html-fromhtmlstring-doesnt-work-for-font-color-text-font) suggests (also updated my question)? Just replace `#FF0000` with `"+color+"`.

Comment: @MSI that is an entirely different question that should not be asked in comments. Nonetheless, here is the link you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: Thank you Phil. It's working perfect! I tried in this way: getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='"+color+"'>"+"Home"+"</font>")); Just has to use ' in place of \.

Comment: @Phil It says that `call requires API 11 or above.`

Comment: @Phil I had to use getSupportActionBar(). Thanks alot.

Comment: @Phil - I am working on Xamarin Android and I tried same code for xamarin but it gives error that "Cannot convert Android.Text.ISpanned to int". Any idea ?

Comment: On modern systems: `HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + "v${BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME}!" + "</font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)`

Answer (score 95):

I was having the same problem as you, it's a Holo.Light theme but I wanted to style the ActionBar color, so I needed to change the text color as well and also both Title and Menus. So at the end I went to git hub and looked at source code until I find the damn correct style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For honeycomb and up -->
<resources>

    <style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbground</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

so now all you have to do is set whatever `@color/actionBarText` and`@drawable/actionbarbground` you want!

Comment: Where i have to use this xml? values or values-v11 or values v-14??

Comment: the answer is from feb/2012, there wasn't V14 on the time. So V11 for sure.

Comment: below 3.0 the system does not have an actionBar.

Comment: I'm using Action Bar Sherlock and I found the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: for actionbar sherlock you have to use the actionbar specific names and you could use this generator: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ We always use it where I work. It's very good

Comment: Here it only changed the Title color, but not the Menu options. :(

Answer (score 68):

The ActionBar ID is not available directly, so you have to do little bit of hacking here.

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` on this line `actionBarTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: In case you're running API level < 11, ActionBarSherlock and you'd like to save yourself an expensive call to `getIndentifier()`, you can look in `(TextView) findViewById(com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.abs__action_bar_title);` first (be sure to check if it's not null).

Comment: "The ActionBar ID is not available directly" actually in my case the toolbar is easily accessible like `Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` where in the xml layout file it is surrounded by `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` element, then `toolbar.setTitleTextColor( getResources().getColor( R.color.colorViolet ) );`

Answer (score 37):

The most straight-forward way is to do this in the styles.xml.

Google's template styles.xml currently generates the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

If you add one more line before the closing  tag, as shown, that will change the text color to what it should be with a Dark ActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

If you want to customize the color to something else, you can either specify your own color in colors.xml or even use a built-in color from Android using the android:textColorPrimary attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

Note: This changes the color of the title and also the titles of any MenuItems displayed in the ActionBar.

Answer (score 36):

It's an old topic but for future readers, using ToolBar makes everything very easy:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: This works great for me. You can also use: toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))

Answer (score 29):

Add it to the root of the action bar. I had this problem.

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/stdDarkBlueText</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/stdDarkBlueText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/stdDarkBlueText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

**actionMenuTextColor** - changes text color for the action bar text, it never worked when it was part of the `Widget.Styled.ActionBar`, so I had to add it to the root. Other 2 attributes change title and subtitle of an action bar.

Comment: Use "android:actionMenuTextColor" instead of "actionMenuTextColor". :)

Answer (score 29):

i have done with simple one line code

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBartitle </font>"));
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially a duplicate of the answer given above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592911/1992342

Comment: Looks like a patch.

Answer (score 19):

Setting a HTML string on the action bar doesn't work on the Material theme in SDK v21+

If you want to change it you should set the primary text color in your style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/actionbar-text-color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This changes the primary text color everywhere in the application!

Answer (score 13):

If you want to style the subtitle also then simply add this in your custom style.

```
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
```

People who are looking to get the same result for `AppCompat` library then this is what I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
     </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_title</item>
      </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I'm trying for a light theme, dark action bar, and white text.  Your code is the only thing I've found so far that has any effect at all, but it turns the whole action bar white.  Any idea what might be going on?  Yes I know this is a year and a half old.  :-)

Comment: This helped me solve my problem. I just needed to add both `<item name="android:titleTextStyle">` _and_ `<item name="titleTextStyle">` because I was using the appcompat support library.

Comment: the title disapear

Answer (score 11):

A lot of answers are deprecated so I'll update the thread and show how to change text color and backgroundcolor on ActionBar (Toolbar) and in ActionBar pop up menu.

The latest approach in Android (as of May 2018) in working with Action bar (Toolbar) is to use Theme with NoActionBar and use Toolbar instead.

so here is what you need:

1. In Activity (which extends AppCompatActivity) declare Toolbar:

   ```
   Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
   ```
2. Add Toolbar in the Activity's layout xml. Here we will set our custom (overwritten themes), note `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar"` and `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu"`, they will do the trick.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   ```
3. In your styles.xml you will have to overwrite those two styles to set custom colors:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
   <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu</item>
   </style>

   <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/action_bar_text_color</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar_bg_color</item>
   </style>

   <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@color/popup_bg_color</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/popup_text_color</item>
   </style>
   ```

That's it folks

p.s. if you ask me I would say: YES, this whole Theme thing is a hell of a mess.

Answer (score 10):

Found the way to do it nicely without creating your own layout on API >= 21.

It will only colorize texts and control drawables inside the action bar.

Hope it will be useful for someone.

```
<!--Material design primary colors-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppBaseTheme.Toolbar</item>
</style>

<!--Action bar-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/action_bar_text</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/action_bar_text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

These functions work well

### In Java

```
private void setActionbarTextColor(ActionBar actBar, int color) {

    String title = actBar.getTitle().toString();
    Spannable spannablerTitle = new SpannableString(title);
    spannablerTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, spannablerTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    actBar.setTitle(spannablerTitle);

}
```

then to use it just feed it your action bar and the new color i.e.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();    // Or getSupportActionBar() if using appCompat
int red = Color.RED
setActionbarTextColor(actionBar, red);
```

---

### In Kotlin

You can use an extension function like this:

```
private fun ActionBar.setTitleColor(color: Int) {
    val text = SpannableString(title ?: "")
    text.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(color),0,text.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    title = text
}
```

And then apply to your `ActionBar` with

```
actionBar?.setTitleColor(Color.RED)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution I used after checking all answers

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Button_color</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Title_Bar_Color</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText"/>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Title_Bar_Color</item>
    <item name="background">@color/Title_Bar_Color</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarSubTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarSubTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/solid_white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Change the required colors it will work

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this in your Activity's onCreate. Works on almost every Android version.

```
 actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffff00'>Your Title</font>"));
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffff00'>Your Title</font>"));
```

Comment: You should put a string like this: 

String coloredTitle = "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + Your_Title + "</font>";

 Html.fromHtml(coloredTitle);

Answer (score 3):

just put this in your thme style.

`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourcolor</item>`

Comment: best answer! its work with themes.xml and parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

Answer (score 2):

Try a lot of methods, in the low version of the API,a feasible method is `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>` and don't use the Android namespace,hope can help you

ps:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is :
 Add these two lines to your styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
...
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Replace the color with your color.

Comment: i have material theme and these lines are not working  here is my code    ``` <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>

    </style>```

Answer (score 1):

Here Style.xml is like

```
 <resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyTheme</item>
</style>


 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```

You should add

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyTheme</item>
```

in AppTheme

Comment: how to do this in material

Comment: Very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I switched to [AndroidX Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) instead of using the native action bar. Also, I rely on [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kts) to access the toolbar from the activity, but you can use `findViewById(...)` for that.

(I removed the code which is irrelevant).

`styles.xml`:

```
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
  ...
</style>
...
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
...
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
  app:titleTextColor="@color/colorOnPrimary"
  ...
/>
...
```

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
  ...

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarMain)
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution is to user a SpannableStringBuilder and set the color that way. You can even use different colors on different parts of the string, add images etc.

Tested with the new support library.

See [Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended solution as I am going in android apis here but as my application requires to change the theme dynmically on conditions  xml not possible here, So I need to do this. But This solution is working very nice.

### Solution:--

```
 /**
 * 
 * @author Kailash Dabhi
 * @email kailash09dabhi@gmail.com
 *
 */ 
 public static void setActionbarTextColor(Activity activity, int color) {
    Field mActionViewField;
    try {
        mActionViewField = activity.getActionBar().getClass()
                .getDeclaredField("mActionView");
        mActionViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mActionViewObj = mActionViewField.get(activity
                .getActionBar());

        Field mTitleViewField = mActionViewObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(
                "mTitleView");
        mTitleViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mTitleViewObj = mTitleViewField.get(mActionViewObj);

        TextView mActionBarTitle = (TextView) mTitleViewObj;
        mActionBarTitle.setTextColor(color);
        // Log.i("field", mActionViewObj.getClass().getName());
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android 5 (lollipop) you will have to use *android:actionBarPopupTheme* to set the *textColor* for the overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can change color of any text by use **html `<font>` attribute** directly in **`xml`** files.
for example in `strings.xml` :

```
<resources>
    <string name = "app_name">
        <html><font color="#001aff">Multi</font></html>
        <html><font color="#ff0044">color</font></html>
        <html><font color="#e9c309">Text </font></html>
    </string>
</resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/color_primary"
  android:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow"
  app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />


<style name="GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
       in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
 
  <!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
       text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->
  <!-- <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item> -->
 
  <!-- android:actionMenuTextColor is the color of the text of
        action (menu) items in the Toolbar, at least in the
        Theme.AppCompat theme.
        For some reason, they already get the textColorPrimary
        when running on API 21, but not on older versions of
        Android, so this is only necessary to support older
        Android versions.-->
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
  <!-- android:textColorSecondary is the color of the menu
       overflow icon (three vertical dots) -->
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light</item>
 
  <!-- This would set the toolbar's background color,
        but setting this also changes the popup menu's background,
        even if we define popupTheme for our <Toolbar> -->
  <!-- <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item> -->
</style>


**Reference:**
[https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the color programmatically this is the way to do it:

```
static void setActionBarTextColor(Activity activity, int color)
{
      ActionBar actionBar = activity instanceof AppCompatActivity
                    ? ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar()
                    : activity.getActionBar();
      String title = activity.getTitle(); // or any title you want
      SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(title);
      ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      actionBar.setTitle(ss);
}
```

Comment: What happens if the title changes ?

Comment: @Humpity if you don't call this function when the title changes you lose the color.

Answer (score 0):

We need to define the theme in our toolbar with app:theme attribute like the below code snippet.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarFont" />
```

Before that, we have to add the theme in our styles.xml file and we have to define font-family in that style like the below code snippet.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarFont" parent="AppTheme">
<!--This line changes the color of text in Toolbar-->
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
<!--This line changes the color of icons in toolbar (back, overflow menu icons)-->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/azul</item>
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semi_bold</item>
```

To add custom fonts we need to create a folder with the name “font” in the res directory like the below screenshot.

[image]

We have achieved a custom font in our toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are using a custom action bar you can use these properties:

```
app:titleTextColor="@color/...."
app:subtitleTextColor="@color/...."
```

###### or by a method like this:

```
setTitleTextColor()
```

for more properties check this [link](https://m2.material.io/components/app-bars-top/android#regular-top-app-bar)