# How to change the Action bar text and background properties?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles

Here is my style for the action bar. I would like to change the text and background properties. But the changes are not being applied to the app. Where am I making mistake?

This is my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">    
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:drawableBottom">@color/actionbar_title_color</item>
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionbar_text_size</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>    
</style>
```

Comment: Tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color) also. But still I am unable to change the color and appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked. It was my mistake. I was changing the style in the values folder. Since I am working on ICS I should have changed it in values-14 folder.