# How To Change Action Bar Text Color

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

How can i change my action bar text color White to Black ? I don't want to use the Action Bar Sherlock .[image]

Here Is My Code For Action Bar .

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33CCFF"));     
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Here is Custom View For Action Bar :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here style.xml :

```
    <resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Comment: u need o change the color of phrase "SIGN UP" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color will help you

Comment: Yes @kathir .How do i change ?

Comment: this link will helpful for you

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color        
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368565/how-to-change-the-action-bar-text-and-background-properties
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317594/actionbar-text-color-change-while-using-actionbarcompat

Comment: if yes, change text color of that `TextView` from `#ffffff` to `#FF000000`...

Comment: Before asking this question ,i do googling , but hopeless

Comment: check my below answer

Comment: @GopalRao Sir : Works

Answer (score 0):

Try this styles:

You can edit your TitleTextStyle inside of styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" 
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style></resources>
```

thanx to rnoway

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"      //  change the color code your wat , instead of #ffffff put youra
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

u can find the color codes from

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use html to set the title, and specify the text color. For example, to set the ActionBar text color to red, simply do this:

```
getActionBar()/* or getSupportActionBar() */.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#000000\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
```