# Why the title of TableLayout are always show in capital letters?

Tags: android

I found a question in tablayout,the title of TableLayout are always show in capital letters,how to solve this problem?

[TableLayout title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1dCY.png)

I get the title text form strings.xml,and the adapter is following:

```
static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}

public static Fragment create() {
    return new SearchFragment();
}
```

}

strings.xml

```
<string name="Repositories">Repositories</string>
<string name="Code">Code</string>
<string name="Issues">Issues</string>
<string name="Users">Users</string>
```

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015652/tablayout-tab-title-text-in-lower-case

Comment: ye.It work.Thanks:-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

it will work

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position).toLowerCase();
    }

}

    public static Fragment create() {
        return new SearchFragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015652/tablayout-tab-title-text-in-lower-case`