# TextAllcaps issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-design

Good Afternoon.

I have implemented `TabLayout` with `viewpager` when tab title text is in **.ttf** format font not working.

I have done Style code, but I'm facing the same problem.

see my xml code ->

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
 android:id="@+id/tabs"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
 android:background="#eceff1"
 app:tabMode="fixed"
 app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

style code ->

```
<style name="CustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
 <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/iconGray</item>
 <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
 <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
 <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CustomTabTextAppearance</item>
 <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
 <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/txt_15</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">#a4dbb2</item>
 <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/amaranth</item>
 <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

I have seen the "questions that may already have your answer", but 
I'm not satisfied with those answers

Thank you in advance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015953/3395198

Comment: Yes, but I want .ttf font or fontfamily with textAllCaps is true in tabs with viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyClass.java -

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
  }
}
```

themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- you should set typeface which you want to override with TypefaceUtil -->
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

TypefaceUtil.java -

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {

    /**
     * Using reflection to override default typeface
     * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
     * @param context to work with assets
     * @param defaultFontNameToOverride for example "monospace"
     * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
     */
    public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
        try {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this code -->  CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(
                new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Amaranth-Regular.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );                                                                                                                 but this code textAllCaps is true when .ttf font not working