# How to set text on tab bar in small letters?

Tags: java, android, tabs

[image]   I wrote Videos but in tab it is coming as VIDEOS all in capitals.I want it to be like "Videos"

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Notes"));
```

Comment: Show your xml code

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857459/how-to-style-actionabar-tab-text-in-android

Comment: Do you mean the title of `tabs`?

Comment: yes title of the tabs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if I didn't misunderstood you'll have to create a `styles.xml` as follows :

```
<style name="CustomTabs" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">YOUR_TEXT_SIZE</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

And then in your `layout` where you put the `TabLayout` add this :

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabs"
```

And if you don't want to show the title without capitalleters you'll have to add on yout `style` this aswell :

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

### SOLUTION

Best way is to add this in your `TabLayout` xml

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

Comment: size get reduced but still in capital letters.

Comment: yes  I added...  <style name="CustomTabs" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>

Comment: In layout also I added    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabs"/>

Comment: thank you , only adding this line "app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"       in layout worked for me, nothing to add in style.XML  .So when I add this line in XML what it does is, it shows the same as it is written.

Comment: Glad to help you, happy coding ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use this **style** to `LayLayout`

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
      <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

make tab `textAllCaps` false

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```