# how to modify the "title_activity_main" text color in the "header" of the app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActionBar text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

[image: I would like to modify the "header" of the app (circled in red), any ideas?]

I would like to modify the color of the text in the"header" of the app (circled in red), any ideas? Manifest or where?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in the manifest. Instead, go to values -> styles and set it to the color of your choice.