# How to change TextColor of Title and it's size shown in SherlockFragmentActivity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have below code of my SherlockFragmentActivity .

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sherlock);

    }
```

Here is how it's look like .

[image: SherlockFragmentActivity]

my problem is i can not able to change Top Title Color in this Activity and i also want to change Background of this SherlockDemo Title .

What is that top header is called? is it  ActionBar with out any action added or any thing else ?

Please let me known how i can do that.

**EDIT My App Theme**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MYAction.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MYAction.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Jake Wharton the creator of ActionBar Sherlock says [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color "this") is the correct way of doing it. You must define your own custom theme.

Comment: you can find it on this 


  http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: I got solution from @Archie.bpgc and that i also post in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a custom theme in the style.xml.

This custom theme must have a parent theme of any of the default ActionBarSherlock themes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
<item name="android:textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
<item name="textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have try your answer but it's does not make any change.

Comment: Can you please add your **style.xml** in the question, after making the changes i suggested

Comment: please also use items **without android: prefix** like in my answer. If you haven't tried that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21817/discussion-between-herry-and-archie-bpgc)