# Android. ActionBar. How to change ActionBar title color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to change ActionBar title color. I tried different ways to do it. But I could not solve this problem. I have created my own actionbar theme in **values/styles.xml** and **values-14/styles.xml**

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">   
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/grey_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_text</item>
</style>
```

**values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/grey_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@color/grey_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_text</item>
</style>
```

grey_text color is **#58585A**. But when I am running on 4.3 device, ActionBar title color is **F3F3F3**.

I am wondering why this is happening. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240605/change-action-bar-title-color

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
  <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
  ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Title">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Subtitle">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you using support library actionbar?

Comment: yes, I am using appcompat_v7. I have created this project in Eclipse. It is default project with built in navigation drawer. May be navigation drawer is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just try method of Activity class "setTitleColor(int color)"

Comment: tried setTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_text)); it is not helping