# Android - Change Actionbar Title Text Color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textview

I'm developing an app and I want to `change the textcolor of the actionbar title`. now, I defined a theme in my manifest:

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

which is defined in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/themeapp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

this doesn't work but I don't get why. this should work according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881739/2139586).neither the textview style is working.

what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
changed to meet Grace Feng answer below

Comment: not yet unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wandering around StackOverflow I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26039521/2139586) which finally worked.

I report it here:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
  <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
  ...
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Title">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Subtitle">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I followed this example setting @color/my_color to #000000, and my text inside the action bar is still white.

Comment: Both the actionBar background and text colors became white.

Answer (score 18):

Using `SpannableString` we can set Text Color of `Actionbar title`

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

<style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
```

You missed a symbol "@" here?

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

also

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextView" parent="@android:Widget.TextView">
```

Comment: oh, this is embarassing. anyway, this is not working anyway, actionbar title remains white and textviews reamains black

Answer (score 4):

You could find how to customize `ActionBar` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27390692/5123494). I recommend to use `ToolBar` and `Theme.AppCompat` instead - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503149/how-do-i-style-appcompat-v7-toolbar-like-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar).

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are using `ToolBar` as `ActionBar`. Of all the answers, I think this is the easiest one to implement. And works on all API versions.

So here it is:

Action bar title uses `textColorPrimary` as its text color. So to change that in styles.xml create a new style with an item for `textColorPrimary` and set whatever color you need.

```
<style name="appBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorRed</item>
</style>
```

Now, add that style as your theme for toolbar in the XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/appBarTheme">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And now you got what you need.

Comment: `android:textColorPrimary` is very precise. I had to look at a lot of answers till I reached this and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `app:titleTextColor="@color/CUSTOM_COLOR"` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/yellow_light"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/CUSTOM_COLOR"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When i got the same problem, i used:

```
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTextStyle</item>

<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTextStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just the problem of you activity.I used the same code as you, and it works.[image]

Firstly ,i used AppCompatActivity as the base activity and get error. and then i use activity and it works.
In my opinion, your code is use for theme for Theme.Holo, and now we use Theme.AppCompat . So if you want change, just reference [Changing Background and text color of AppCompat Light DarkActionBar Theme on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957822/changing-background-and-text-color-of-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-theme-on-and). 
It works for me.Good luck for you.

Comment: I have a NavigationDrawer in the activity, so it extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity. unfortunately I didn't write this code so I don't really know why the guy who written this used it this way :S

Comment: I see AbstractNavDrawerActivity and this activity is extended from ActionBarActivity. And your theme is form Theme.Holo . So it will not work. If you do not want to change the activity , just change the theme like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957822/changing-background-and-text-color-of-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-theme-on-and. it will work

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've used `style` instead of `theme`. [Styles and themes differ](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/). So replace

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

With

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: if I put this like you suggested android studio is not able to find it and returns an error, all the suggestion include `:style`

Comment: I did. I understend I should not use it for the application tab but rather for sigle views. But then my questio remains, how do I change the text color?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution, but I was able to change the text color between white and black with this method.

so, in the styles.xml you have:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

if you change what's inside the parent="..." to dark or light themes, it adapts the text color to these themes. For example, right now you have a dark theme, and the text is white, but when I change to "Theme.AppCompat.Light" the text color turns black.

Hope it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Activity` theme as:

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem, finally figured it out.
In your style.xml do not specify a background color for your toolbar.
Then define the color in each layout.xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#B678EE"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

This gives you the flexibility to be able to easily have different action bar colors depending on the activity if need be as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a usable code. Follow this code.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorApp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">23dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

In second style tag we customize the actionBar title.

Now Add this above code in the application in `Manifest File`

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity>  .....  </activity>
        <activity>  .....  </activity>
</application>
```