# Set ActionBarDrawerToggle text color

Tags: android

I want to change the text color of my app name that is appearing adjacent to the 3 lines that is used to open and close the drawer.
It is black in color and i want to change it to white color, how can i do it
any help

Comment: Check this link http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: i got the answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240605/change-action-bar-title-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This single line of code will do the job

```
getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>The Title</font>"));
```

This will set red color for your Action Bar title. :)

Try the following as an alternate way. change ActionBarStyle to

```
   <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
     <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: its working , but i dont want to give the title of my app in hard coded string in the place of title, it is in a variable so can u tell me how to put a varaible inside an html code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>YourTitleHere </font>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting application or activity theme to

```
   @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Comment: are you using appcompat??