# Action bar title textcolor in not getting changed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using following style.xml and trying to set background and text color of action bar but background color is applied and text color dosent apper please suggest some solution my code of

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.titleTextStyle</item>
</style><style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#417bde</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar.titleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Action Bar Title color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240605/change-action-bar-title-color)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240605/change-action-bar-title-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

Comment: Your MyTheme Parent is coming from Holo.Light and ActionBar.TitleTextStyle has a parent specified as AppCompat

Comment: then @skynet how to solve it

Comment: [Get the basics right](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance)

Comment: Move to using Toolbars, they are much flexible than Actionbars

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); // or getSupportedActionBar() for lower version

actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"YOUR COLOR CODE\">" + YOUR CUSTOM TEXT + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed title color like this

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this code?

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">your_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">your_color</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: it only changes color not background

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.titleTextStyle</item>
</style><style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#417bde</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```