# how to change color in actionbar title

Tags: java, android

I want to change the color , but do not know how, please help me
Now the text color black, but i want to change the color to white
where i can read about it ?

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings"
    />`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUnn3.png)

Comment: `android:titleTextColor="#ffffff"`

Comment: In Stackoverflow already have same question with some answers at [Change Action Bar Title Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240605/change-action-bar-title-color)

Answer (score 0):

File styles.xml or colors.xml has value with color for ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can change it in `colors.xml` attribute `colorPrimary`.

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
```