# How do I change the color of a text menu item with ActionBarCompat?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I have the title color set correctly, but I'm not sure what I need to style to change the menu "icon" text color in the ActionBarCompat. I want the "Login/Join" text to be white.

Sorry, I'm sure the solution is out there on StackOverflow, but I haven't been able to string together the right keywords to find it :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to change that value programmatically or via xml aside from altering the base parent theme. I ended up changing my theme to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` and set the titleTextStyle (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881739/413254). I was inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` which naturally makes all text in the actionbar dark. Another option was to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (which would have saved me a lot from multiple xml style headaches).

One of those situations where you get caught up in the details and miss the more fundamental things :P. Hope this helps somebody.