# Android Flat ActionBar (without shadow)

Tags: android

i'm trying to create the a flat action bar without shadow

attached image:

[image]

my style xml

```
<resources>

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bg</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

I'm supporting android 4.x

Any ideas ? I tried changing the style to Solid/Inverse didn't work..

white_bg attached (It's hard to see since it's white)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it should look like this

```
<resources>

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

            <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bg</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

Comment: I actually wanted the opposite; mainly, android:windowContentOverlay = @drawable/my_shadow and android:windowActionBarOverlay = true. This solution works for that scenario if @null is replaced with the name of the desired shadow drawable. Thanks!

Comment: this works, but, it removes the actionbar title, what can i do to get it back?

Comment: @Edgar try changing the title text color [link on how to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Answer (score 1):

The null `windowContentOverlay` attribute should be set on your `Activity` theme (`CustomActionBarTheme`), not on the `ActionBar` theme.