# Android Action Bar Style Generator : Change text color of action bar not available?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

I use "Android Action Bar Style Generator" website to generate styles for my actionBar.

There is no possibility to change the text color of actionBar ?

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=RoseNormal&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=e64260%2C100&secondaryColor=b8344c%2C100&tabColor=fff%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

get id of `textView` on `Actionbar` ( actionBarTitleId ) then do what ever you want. change size, color and ....

if you want use style and for more info see [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)