# Changing Color of Tab Text in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have an app using the support ActionBarActivity `(android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity)`, **with tabs**. I used the Action Bar Style Generator to change the look of the app, but now I am having a hard time getting the tab text color to change.

The style is being applied through the `manifest`, and shows up just fine except for the tab text color remains black no matter what I try. Here's what I have in my custom styles xml file right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">   
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_StyledActionBar</item>   
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.StyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.StyledActionBar.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.StyledActionBar</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.StyledActionBar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

As you can see, I tried to change the color to white, but to no effect. I also was trying to change the Action Bar title color, but gave up because I found a java workaround.

Comment: Switch to AppCompatActivity and TabLayout, and take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31153743/4409409

Comment: As for getting to work with ActionBar Tabs, try adding `android:`  to make it `<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>`   See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24605444/4409409

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

And you are using `Theme.AppCompat` : [ActionBarActivity is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio)

Try to use `AppCompatActivity` in your java codes(`Activity`).

Comment: I appreciate the input. In the meantime, is there a solution that retains ActionBarActivity?