# Don't change the text color of action bar in my android app

Tags: android

i want to do an orange action bar with text withe. I've done the following theme

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
   <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FF6600</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

In the end i've setted the theme in the manifest; but when i run the app the text color of title of the action bar is black ( instead white). What i have to do ?

Comment: go through this answer.... this may help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: BTW, did you changed the style.xml code on all files? You have a style.xml in values, values-v11 and values-v14 folders.