# change action bar title color Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I wants to change the action bar title color to white in android . and i am using theme in values `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and values-14 `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
I have tried so far
in values folder :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and values -14 folder

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

but ActionBar title color is not changing.

Comment: You can find some answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the background color of the `ActionBar` by using the `colorPrimary` attribute; something like the following:

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

The above is a special tag created for `AppCompat`; you will notice that the `android:` namespace is omitted.

Comment: The question was changing the text color not the background color. Yes you can set `colorPrimary` on AppCompat similar to Material action bar, but you can't set `textColorPrimary` in the same regard, which is why he is asking the question.

Comment: Question asks the method to change actionbar text color, not the color of action bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar do

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check that in you layout xml file you don't have an `android:theme` attribute specified, which would have priority over the main theme