# How to change the text color in Android Action bar

Tags: android

Hello I need help on changing the text color of the action Bar the following is my style.xml.I need to change the text color to white including the settings icon.

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

The String.xml source codes are as follows.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">yebo</string>

    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change in your style.

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

**Add underneath line:**

```
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">Your Color Here</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">Your Color Here</item>
</style>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: textColorPrimary will then change the text color in other places, such as the overflow popup menu

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put color to your strings like this:

```
<string name="app_name"><![CDATA[<b><font color=#FFFFFF>yebo</b>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .axml put a RelativeLayout to add the actionbar. In here add a TextView with the property android:textColor="#FFFFFF". (#FFFFFF is white). As such:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBarLinearLayoutFrontPage"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="#696969">
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/txtActionBarText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Action Bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Valus/styles.xml uses colors.xml file. When you press "control" and click @color/colorPrimary it shows you where colorPrimary comes. Which is colors.xml. In your colors.xml file you can edit it.

[image: Colors.xml]

When you click the colour on the left it opens color palette. And you can change it easily.
[image: Color palette]