# TextView color is always white for AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-styles

The text color of a `TextView` is always white on pre-Marshmallow devices. Even if I am using yellow or black in my XML, it is always white except on Marshmallow.

At run time it will work fine on all devices. Previously, when I was using Eclipse, everything was working find but in Android Studio it is not taking the attribute from the XML.

All of the questions I have searched say to change `Theme.AppCompat` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` but this does nothing except change white to black. I believe there is a style mistake. Here is my style code:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/khaki</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/khaki</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_yellow</item>

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>
```

Here is my xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="48dp">
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
     android:src="@drawable/sj_icon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="34dp"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:text="hello"
    android:textColor="@color/my_yellow"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your layout's XML file, how are you setting the text color? Are you using `android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"` inside the `<TextView>` tag?

Comment: Same problem after android studio update... In new project works fine, in old project textColor not working.

Comment: @McAdam.... I am using  android:textColor="@color/my_yellow" or     android:textColor="#000000"  black color but I am still getting white color in device..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890832/how-to-change-the-text-color-in-android-action-bar/35890901#35890901

Comment: @Ancee i think you have values-v21 folder in your project?

Comment: @ jaydroider that is for actiobar color... and i also added <item name="textColorPrimary">Your Color Here</item> but it is still not working

Comment: @ jaydroider.. i can guess in values textcolor is hardcode to white ... as i change my theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light it is changing to black color .. but where it is happening i dunno..

Comment: @Ancee You mean yellow color is not showing at design mode instead of it is showing white at design mode always.

Comment: @ jaydroider ... no in design it is showing yellow ..but at run time in device it is always showing white.. but in marshmalo device it is working fine...

Comment: @Ancee You mean problem is only come to lower versions then marshmallow. Are you testing in real device or emulator ?

Comment: @ balaji... I am hust using value folder.. no 21,23 or any other value folder...

Comment: @jaydroider.. yes in lower devices.. and using real devices sir..

Comment: @Ancee Try by setting text color programetically this might be solve your probelm. Do this yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106315/discussion-between-ancee-and-jaydroider).

Comment: @Ancee tell me your colorPrimary , colorPrimaryDark color code?

Comment: Are you using Stable or Beta version of Android Studio? I experienced similar strange issues in Beta versions of Android Studio. If you are using Beta version please try to use a Stable version. Also sometimes renaming the resource names do the trick for me in such scenarios. So try to rename your xml layout and see whether it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer of my problem actually I was using latest version of support library that was creating problem I compare everything with my colleague project as his app was working fine..
use this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

studio will give popup a newer version is also available but don't use that as 24 version is in alpha stage.

Comment: Please tell me your exact problem.. @PriyankaMinhas

Answer (score 1):

I faced a problem similar to this (in a widget, the text color was white if the average of RGB values is more than half the max value and black if not)

I was testing the app in a phone having the "high contrast text" feature enabled, so the solution was disabling it.