# Android EditText Text Color is always white

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-appcompat

Good day all,

I have an issue that's truly maddening.
For some reason the textColor attribute for the EditText component in my custom theme is not taking effect.

*Please note that everything else for my custom theme is working, it's just the 'textColor' part that is giving trouble.*

I've seen other people with the same issue, and their 'solutions' aren't working for me.

[Articles referenced before posting this]
[TextView color is always white for AppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987952/textview-color-is-always-white-for-appcompatactivity) 
[Edittext color is white in appcompat 22.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114541/edittext-color-is-white-in-appcompat-22-2)

[My Code and Setup]

**Android Studio Version**
2.1.1

**CustomTheme XML Snippet**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
  <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomEditText</item> <!-- I'm extending AppCompatActivity, hence no 'android:' prefix! -->
</style>

<style name="CustomEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

**Android Manifest XML Snippet**

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">...</application>
```

**build.gradle (app) Snippet**

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' <!-- I've even tried this version v7:23.4.0 -->
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you please share the layout containing the EditText

Comment: @youzking Thank you for suggesting that I post the layout. When I was copying the layout code to update my question, I recognized that the 'textColor' was being set to white in the layout xml itself, and that caused the issue. Thanks a mil, what a silly mistake.

Comment: you are most welcome, glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment by [youzking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4043486/youzking) asking for a copy of the activity layout. I saw that I was setting the 'textColor' to white in the layout xml for the Activity. Hence, that was the issue as it was overriding the theme 'textColor'.