# Actionbar item color

Tags: java, android

this is the style that I am using for my app:

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

and this my toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

So my toolbar (or actionbar) is kind of dark blue. By default all the Text on the actionbar is black as well as the tree dots signalizing the options menu at the right end of the screen. My aim is to get those items white.
When setting textColorPrimary to white, the tree dots remain black as well as any text within an EditView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890832/how-to-change-the-text-color-in-android-action-bar/35890901#35890901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using Light version which will tint the icon to black [see here](http://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html)

Change the theme to get white icon in the background:

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Thanks @Rod_Algonquin. It works. However the back button and the three dots are less white than any text within the action bar.