# Cannot Change Action Bar Text Color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I have read several threads on this topic and have implemented the below code. However, I cannot change change the text color of my Action Bar text:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

Comment: tried it, did not work for me, it shrunk the ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
    </style>
```

I use Toolbar and this works for me. Too bad i couldn't repeat it with inheritance.