# Html.fromHtml deprecated when setting action bar title colour

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

After updating the target SDK version to 24.0.0, `fromHtml` becomes strikethroughed and a deprecation warning is returned. When it comes to setting the title of the action bar, what needs to change in order to resolve this error?

Minimum API is 17

```
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + getResources().getString(R.string.welcome) + "</font>"));
```

> 'fromHtml(java.lang.String)' is deprecated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, use [the version of `fromHtml()` that takes some flags as a parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)). AFAIK, `FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY` would be the flag value to use for compatibility with the older flag-less `fromHtml()`.

If your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 24, your choices are:

- Always use the `fromHtml()` you are, possibly using the quick-fix (<kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd>) to suppress the Lint warning
- Use both versions of `fromHtml()`: the one taking the flags if your app is running on an API Level 24+ device, or the one without the flags on older devices

The latter would look like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(..., Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}
else {
  actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(...));
}
```

(where `...` is your HTML to convert)

Note, though, that if you are simply trying to change the color of the entire action bar title, use [Sandro Machado's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028988/115145). `Html.fromHtml()` and similar `Spanned`-based solutions are for cases where you need different colors for different pieces of text within a single `TextView` (or something using a `TextView`, such as the action bar).

Answer (score 2):

You should user other methods.

If you use a toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

A style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Find more ways here: [ActionBar text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Comment: You can and should use the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. Check it here: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html