# How to set Title Text Color on Android Custom Action Bar for version less than 3.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Here are the specs for my android platform from my Build.gradle script for my application

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 26
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
```

Below is the style i included in my STYLES.XML file:

```
<style name="customStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/customActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/custom</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">#01579B</item>
    </style>
```

Please can any one briefly help with how to set the title text color on the action bar. Thank you.

```
<item name="titleTextColor">#01579B</item>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881739/6248491

Comment: didn't change it still. It's still white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this item your ActionBar style templet

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
```

or

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```