# How to change android top text color

Tags: android, kotlin

How to change **Guincho7** color from **white** to **black**?

[image]

Comment: Is that an `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` or...what is it? Can you post your layout?

Comment: use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as parent in your app theme.

Comment: Guncho is toolbar ?

Comment: try this :-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40035506/7455793

Answer (score 0):

You can add titleTextColor property to the Toolbar element in your view's XML file.

```
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
```