# Android change color part of a string

Tags: android, textview

I have a string name "classe". It contains  many words and phrases in it. But I want to change color when string contains the word `"idiom"`. I did that programmatically, but it changed the color of all string "classe". I just want to change the color of "idiom" (a part of word, not the whole phrase). How can I do that programmatically?

```
    if (classe.contains("idiom")) {

        txtclasse.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change part of text color within an "EditText" widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524976/change-part-of-text-color-within-an-edittext-widget)

Comment: Use ForegroundColorSpan. Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3514435/4586742

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089362/6667442

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628947/12478830

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ForegroundColorSpan.

```
if(classe != null && classe.contains(“idiom”))
{
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(classe);
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), classe.indexOf(“idiom”), classe.indexOf(“idiom”) + “idiom”.length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txtclasse.setText(spannable);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTML to solve it.

```
origString = txtclasse.getText().toString();
origString = origString.replaceAll("idiom","<font color='red'>idiom</font>");

txtclasse.setText(Html.fromHtml(origString));
```

Comment: It didn't work! The whole string phrase were empty on screen :(