# Searchview doesn't work when I type space for firestore adapter

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, searchview

I cant search with two word type like "jack jones" its only work for single word("jack") how can I figure it out? Here is my code:

```
private void searchData(String s) {
        adapter.stopListening();
        query = notebookRef.whereEqualTo("isim", s.toLowerCase()).orderBy("isim", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Profiles> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Profiles>()
                .setQuery(query, Profiles.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreAdapterForProfiles(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();


    }
```

Comment: See my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/

Comment: actually I didnt understand can you convert my code?

Comment: My code is in Kotlin meanwhile you are programming in Java. You can convert it. It makes searched text colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured out here is the code that I changed:

```
query = notebookRef.orderBy("isim").startAt(s.toLowerCase()).endAt(s+"\uf8ff");
```