# How to hightlight the typed text in searchview in android

Tags: android, search

Hi in the MainActivity I was Implemented a Different Fragments.Now toolbar contains a searchview functionality I was added in my Activity.

Now I search for text all the fragement are also searching for same text.But I want to clear the text which one i typed for last fragement.

MainActivity:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 setSearchtollbar();

 public void setSearchtollbar()
    {
        searchtollbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.searchtoolbar);
        if (searchtollbar != null) {
            searchtollbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_search);
            search_menu=searchtollbar.getMenu();

            searchtollbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                    else
                        searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            item_search = search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search);

            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item_search, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                    }
                    else
                        searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true;
                }
            });

            initSearchView();


        } else
            Log.d("toolbar", "setSearchtollbar: NULL");
    }

    public void initSearchView()
    {
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();

        // Enable/Disable Submit button in the keyboard

        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

        // Change search close button image

        ImageView closeButton = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
      // closeButton.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplication(), R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp));


        // set hint and the text colors

        EditText txtSearch = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text));
        txtSearch.setHint("Search..");
        txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        txtSearch.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));





        // set the cursor

        AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        try {
            Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
            mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.search_cursor); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                callSearch(query);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                callSearch(newText);
                return true;
            }

            public void callSearch(String query) {

                Log.i("query", "" + query);

            }

        });

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void circleReveal(int viewID, int posFromRight, boolean containsOverflow, final boolean isShow)
    {
        final View myView = findViewById(viewID);

        int width=myView.getWidth();

        if(posFromRight>0)
            width-=(posFromRight*getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material))-(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material)/ 2);
        if(containsOverflow)
            width-=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material);

        int cx=width;
        int cy=myView.getHeight()/2;

        Animator anim;
        if(isShow)
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0,(float)width);
        else
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, (float)width, 0);

        anim.setDuration((long)220);

        // make the view invisible when the animation is done
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if(!isShow)
                {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        // make the view visible and start the animation
        if(isShow)
            myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // start the animation
        anim.start();


    }
```

Fragment:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.search:


                return true;
            case R.id.refresh:
                fetchJSON();
                return true;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Menu:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi

Comment: @How to pass from activity to fragment

Comment: After you pass string from activity to fragment, you can use my code in that answer to make text colored.

Comment: Which String I should pass From Mainactivity to fragment

Comment: The string that you want to be highlighted

Comment: @MMG how to pass searchview from activity to fragment

Comment: You shouldn't pass searchview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213599/discussion-between-jyo-srijyo-and-mmg).