# Highlighting search text in recyclerview in android

Tags: android, search

How to highlight search text result in RecyclerView. I found some posts regarding Spannable TextView, but not sure where to implement in my case. Appreciate you can look and assist.

Can any one help it is not highlight the search text

```
     public void onSearch(String query){
            Log.d("Query From Activity",query);
            ArrayList<TaskModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            //resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            for (int i = 0; i < listTask.size(); i++) {

                final String jTitle = listTask.get(i).getAssigned().toLowerCase();
             //   final String jCompany = listTask.get(i).getJob_company().toLowerCase();
              //  final String jLoc = mDataList.get(i).getJob_location().toLowerCase();
                if (jTitle.contains(query) ) {
                    // make them also bold

                    filteredList.add(listTask.get(i));
                    highlightText(query,jTitle);
                  //  resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   // listTask.get(i).setText(sb);
                } else {
                //    resultView.setText("No results found for : " + query);
                  //  resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
            final LinearLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerViewTask.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(getContext(),filteredList,this,this);
            recyclerViewTask.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
            taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

public static CharSequence highlightText(String search, String originalText) {
        if (search != null && !search.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "").toLowerCase();
            int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);
            if (start < 0) {
                return originalText;
            } else {
                Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
                while (start >= 0) {
                    int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                    int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(), originalText.length());
                    highlighted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
                }
                return highlighted;
            }
        }
        return originalText;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi

Comment: @MMG code in java

Comment: Java and Kotlin aren't so different, make an effort, you should manage it. All you really need to know is how to use `BackgroundColorSpan`, the rest is just finding the position of the query in the texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we have searched characters colored when we use searchview in recyclerview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi)