# android setSpan to editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

For a long time i been confused by the `setSpan` as it looks so easy but not always working as expected

In my last attempt i am trying to `setSpan` to recognized patterns. 
When user starts typing "5 kilo toma" the "5 kilo" will be highlighted.

I used the next code to do that as part of the `TextWatcher` listener

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String quantity = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantity();

        if (!quantity.isEmpty()) {
            int index = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantityIndex();
            final StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC );
            s.setSpan( styleSpan, index, index + quantity.length(), Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
        }
    }
```

This is working correctly (basic testing)

[image]

But if i start deleting the text to read "5 kil", the `setSpan` does not refresh to normal when pattern no longer detected

[image]

So i was thinking, perhaps the `setSpan` is kept in memory or something and i need to set entire string span every time. So i tried the next code:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.length() > 0) {

            String quantity = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantity();
            int index = 0;

            if (!quantity.isEmpty()) {
                index = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantityIndex();
                StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC );
                s.setSpan( styleSpan, index, index + quantity.length(), Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
            }

            StyleSpan styleSpanNormal = new StyleSpan( Typeface.NORMAL );
            s.setSpan( styleSpanNormal, index + quantity.length(), s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
        }
    }
```

But still not working correctly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59628947/12478830

Comment: using the setSpan with ForegroundColorSpan does work but does not solve the problem i mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i understand it more now.

Please correct me if i am wrong and don't hurry to downgrade.

I was confused to think that the `EditText.getText()` was returning a `String` and even when i see that the `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` using the `Editable`, i still thought it was a similar object.

Only now that i noticed i could use `getText()`, then `setSpan` without using the `setText`, that i realized i am actually getting the actual object and thus manipulate it directly.

The meaning of this is that with every `getText()` or using `TextWatcher` listener, the old `setSpan` still exists and i need to clear it.

At first i thought `clearSpans()` will do the trick but it seems to also clear everything else. So instead, i first set the default span and only then set the correct one

For example:

```
//Clear old span
s.setSpan( new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.TRANSPARENT),
                0,
                s.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );

//set new span
s.setSpan( new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.RED),
                    indexStart,
                    indexStart + mQuantity.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
```

In addition, i noticed that the Autocomplete adapter and the TextWatcher order was not always the same. When using log i noticed that mostly the TextWatcher firing before the autocomplete but not always. Either that or perhaps that one can fire while the other?! i am not sure.

Anyway, since the order is significant as the adapter examines the text, i used `MutableLiveData<String>` to keep track of the `mQuantity` value and modify span accordigly

```
//In AutoComplete adapter
public MutableLiveData<String> getQuantity() {
    if (mQuantity == null) {
        mQuantity = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return mQuantity;
}

//In handler constructor
mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantity().observe( (LifecycleOwner) activity, new 
Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            mQuantity = s;
            refreshSpans();
        }
    } );

private void refreshSpans() {
    Editable s = mTextView.getText();
    clearEditTextSpan(s);

    if (!mQuantity.isEmpty()) {
        //Set span
        int indexStart = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getQuantityIndex();

        s.setSpan( new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.RED),
                indexStart,
                indexStart + mQuantity.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
    } 
}

private void clearEditTextSpan(Editable s) {
    s.setSpan( new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.TRANSPARENT),
            0,
            s.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK );
}
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should try the `textChangedListener` as its method `onTextChanged` will help you to check the text while user is typing new text,deleting some text in textview

```
textview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after{

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               //place your code here
               //the code here will work when user is changing the text

            }
```