# How to color part of TextView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to change the color of certain words (Search results) in a `TextView`? I tried to use ANSI colors like this:

```
text.setText("\u001B31;1m" + "someText");
```

but it did not work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this will help u

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, 13, 
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Comment: 5 , 13 are the charecter,s length.

Comment: you mean start and finish indexes?

Comment: Yes. i.e for which part you want to color the text. starting point and ending point of the colored text view.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `TextAppearanceSpan` and 'SpannableString'
To be more clear workflow is as follow

1. Create SpannableString from your source String
2. Create TextAppearanceSpan and set it via call to setSpan method on SpannableString
3. Call textView.setText method with SpannableString as argument

Answer (score 2):

You can also use HTML like in the following example:

```
string = "<font color='#FFFFFF'>This is my text </font>" + "<font color='#000000'> Another text </font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(string));
```

Without using additional variable (one-line solution):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>This is my text </font>" + "<font color='#000000'> Another text </font>"));
```

It is quite easy and understandable solution :)

Comment: Html.fromHtml(string) is deprecated now. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late for the party but I think this is going to help future visitors out.

You might wanna set partial text colors on the layout XML instead of using Java code, so based on previous answers on this thread I've created a small class that does the trick.

**1 - First let's create our component**

```
package yourpackagehere.component;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import yourpackagehere.R;

public class FontSpannableTextView extends TextView {

    public FontSpannableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontSpannableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setColorPartialString(context, attrs);
    }

    public FontSpannableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setColorPartialString(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setColorPartialString(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }
        String partialText = null;
        int partialTextColor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontSpannableTextView);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.getIndexCount(); i++) {
                int attr = a.getIndex(i);
                switch (attr) {
                    case R.styleable.FontSpannableTextView_fontspannabletextview_partialText:
                        partialText = a.getString(attr);
                        break;
                    case R.styleable.FontSpannableTextView_fontspannabletextview_partialTextColor:
                        partialTextColor = a.getColor(attr, Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                }
            }
            a.recycle();
        }

        if (partialText != null && partialTextColor != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            String wholeText = getText().toString();
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(wholeText);
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(partialTextColor),
                    wholeText.indexOf(partialText),
                    wholeText.indexOf(partialText) + partialText.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            setText(spannable);
        } else {
            Log.e("YOURTAGHERE","You must provide both partialText and partialTextColor values");
        }
    }
}
```

**2 - on attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FontSpannableTextView">
        <attr name="fontspannabletextview_partialText" format="string" />
        <attr name="fontspannabletextview_partialTextColor" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**3 - Let's use it in our test layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <yourpackagehere.component.FontSpannableTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" <!-- Hello world! -->
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        app:fontspannabletextview_partialText="@string/world" <!-- world! -->
        app:fontspannabletextview_partialTextColor="@color/tutorial_yellow"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I have been working on android since a decade but even in 2020 this seems to be a major problem with `TextView` in android.