# Set background color for text inside the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

How can I set the `background color` of text inside the `edittext` by programmatically, 
or
Can we set different `textColor` for text in the same edittext at a time, which means if I have a text in my editText1 like "Joe and 10 more", and can I set blue color for Joe and black for other words.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for my english :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7347762/964741

Comment: Try this : EditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy let me try on this solution; seems to be work :)

Comment: Please first search for your question, check if it's already asked on StackOverflow or not. Your one is already there, please use the answers and close this question.

Comment: I have searched for an hour but not found what I want, thats y I asked the question. May be some another one just like me get help if this question is not closed.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy Unfortunately its not working inside editText, but working on TextView :(