# Android How to get selected word in Edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, highlight

I am developing an app like Notepad in which I want to change the selected text formatting dynamically (colors, changing font styles, bold, italic, underline etc.)
How can I format a specific word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the selected word using `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` method :

```
EditText etx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editext);

int startSelection=etx.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=etx.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = etx.getText().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

---

Then you can apply your specific formatting by using this  selected **substring** in the full string after taking it to a **SpannableStringBuilder** on a button click/some other event:

### Code for formatting text:

```
  int startSelection=etx.getSelectionStart();
  int endSelection=etx.getSelectionEnd();

                  final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(etx.getText().toString());

                        final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
                        final StyleSpan iss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC); // Span to make text italic                                     
                        sb.setSpan(iss, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                        sb.setSpan(bss, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                        etx.setText(sb);
```

---

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext).

Comment: @Imaran If user select some text at runtime than How can I know what is the "startSelection" and "endSelection" value? Can u give me suggestion for this?

Comment: You are using `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd();` method to get those value. So think there is a button namely **ITALIC**. After selecting the text user will click this button to get italic effect. Then you can get those value on the button click event like:  `ITALIC.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      int startSelection=etx.getSelectionStart();
         int endSelection=etx.getSelectionEnd();
           
         }
  });`

Comment: @Imaran. Thanks a lot for giving your time. Its working great.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = et1.getText().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

Hope this code suits yours case