# Android: Is there a way to detect pre-defined keywords and color it differently in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an Android project that needs to detect some pre-defined keywords in the EditText, and then color those keywords differently from the other non-keywords, it's like Syntax Coloring in Eclipse.

For Example:
The pre-defined word is

#### stackoverflow!

So, when the user type in the keyword stackoverflow in the EditText, it will color the keyword-stackoverflow and should look like:

[image]

Is there anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Android provides a class called `SpannableStringBuilder` to achieve this..check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897412/2310673)..

Comment: bakriIsOnFireToday :)

Comment: Thanks! bakriIsOnFire!