# Dynamically change Textview size

Tags: android, performance

Is it possible to change the single textView size dynamically?
In the below link the text size is dynamically changed. ? can anyone guide me on how to do this. thanks in advance
[image: Dynamic text size]

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? Change the whole text to a specific size, or have a different size for each letter?

Comment: Please refers the link may help you 

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Comment: buddy Do you have seperate textview for each letter that is in different textsize??

Comment: Is your problem get solved? If you found any solution, you should post it..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all, at-last i used three different textview to design whatever i need. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), start, end,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Here, you need to set `start` and `end` as per your requirement. `0.8f` is size of text here. You need to pass `float` value here.

**Code**

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Spannable span = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), 0, 7,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.8f), 7,
            txt.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txt.setText(span);
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is what he means.

Comment: I think above asked for each text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `SpannableStringBuilder` to styling the text.
Same question is registered at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)