# Android: color specific words in values/strings

Tags: android, xml, string, colors

so I got a string like this:

```
<string name="colorThis">This is red.</string>
```

I'd like to have 'This' in red. Is there any possible way of doing so? I find out that regular XML-formatting doesn't work. Also I know how to color the full string. But a single word? Halp plz

Comment: Try out this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34961310/2183890)

Answer (score 2):

You can use html for this.
Try like this:

```
<string name="colorThis"><![CDATA[<font color="red">This is red.</font>]]></string>
```

or like this

```
<string name="colorThis"><![CDATA[<font color="#FF0000">This is red.</font>]]></string>
```

and then set your text like this: `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.colorThis)));`

Comment: My xml resource is complaining about the appstrophe (building in eclipse) Why

Comment: You need to escape appstrophe in xml with a backslash like this:  \'

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `Html.fromHtml` and, of course, using an html tag. An alternative could be to use a `SpannableString` but, of course, you have to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableStringBuilder for different colors on a string. Pls check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)