# Custom EditText UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view

How do I create a Custom edit text UI like this where hint won't disappear when I type the input.
So the basic idea is when I am typing the credit card number the `X` digit should get replaced with the `number` I have typed. Also, the user is not allowed to enter digit in any order rather he can only enter the input in a sequential manner here's the screenshot for reference.

**Edit: So I was thinking to add 16 different edit text where pressing backspace would take user to previous edit text and only first edit-text would be focusable has anyone has a better solution for this.**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pratham, Have you tried anything or you are facing some issues in the implementation?

Comment: No I am curious how should I approach this custom view

Comment: I am gonna start implementing it tonight

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the XXX as the text, not as a hint, and use Spannable to set the color of the text, if X -> color grey, if number -> color white

How to set different colors for edittext using spanable:
[edittext with different color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312824/edittext-with-different-color-in-android?lq=1)

For skipping where the spaces are - use 4 edittexts and set focus to navigate to the next edittext

Comment: What about user cannot enter text anywhere in between. If you set the text to XXXX user can enter the text anywhere in between

Comment: set an OnFocusListener, if user taps a character focus will always go to start of first edittext

Comment: @prathamkesarkar did you manage to do this? I actually just posted a tutorial for the multiple edittexts approach which might assist you https://medium.com/@Lev_Sharone/create-your-own-customized-pin-code-layout-in-3-simple-steps-e36d560689f8

Comment: actually I did with some hacks