# Get TextView.append to set color on Android

Tags: java, android, colors, textview, append

I am developping a little chat application on Android and I want to make the usernames colored whenever they send message so basicly I have a TextView which displays messages

```
outputView.append("\n"+event.getSender()+": "+event.getMessage());
```

For now I have that, the problem is that I have a single TextView which display the username and the messages all at one. How can I give a color to the username which is `event.getSender()`

Thank you !

**EDIT** : As NKN told me to do I changed it to this. Yet, I still can't get it to work, it simply crashes ... Have I written anything wrong ?

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(event.getSender());
   final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

   // Span to set text color to some RGB value
   final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

   // Span to make text bold
   sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // Set the text color for first 4 characters
   sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

   // make them also bold
   outputView.setText("\n"+sb+": "+event.getMessage());
```

Comment: You can use spannable string. Check with below answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Html` class, for example:

`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color="#FF0000">This is a red text</font> and this one is <b>bold</b>");`

Further, you may also use `SpannableStringBuilder`, I recommend reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)

Comment: But can I put the string event.getSender() and event.getMessage() in it ? I mean can they get colored as well ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but in that case you'll probably want to use `SpannableStringBuilder` instead of `Html` because the first one gives you the possibility of coloring just a part of the string defined by char indexes. I recommend having a look at the link I provided, that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I frist tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/4897386/3191131 but the app crashes ... So I guess i'll try the first code on your link and I'll see what it gives.

Comment: The app still crashes with SpannableStringBuilder any solutions ?

Comment: Update your post with the crash you're getting.

Comment: I can't find the crash report, I'm new to Eclipse. I was debugging with my phone.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, open the LogCat window, there should appear the error. Go to Window -> Show view -> LogCat (if it doesn't appear, click on Other and type LogCat).