# Most efficient way for Dynamic Text Color Change in TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I want to change color of parts of a text several times with a timer.

Simplest way is this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mainText);
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
ssb.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
tv.setText(ssb);
```

But if I run the above code several times in a second, I actually change the whole (large) text of `TextView` each time so a unwanted memory-CPU load will happen specifically on lower-end devices.

How can I have a single `Span` on `TextView` and only change the `Span` start and end position?

Will it work at all or a full text replace will happen behind the scene?

My text is fixed and won't change never.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution for span movement without calling `setText` method:**

```
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setTextSize(32);
    setContentView(tv);

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789");
    ssb.append(ssb).append(ssb);
    tv.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    final Spannable sp = (Spannable) tv.getText();
    final ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(0xffff0000);
    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sp.setSpan(span, start, start + 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            start++;
            if (start <= sp.length() - 4) {
                tv.postDelayed(this, 50);
            }
        }
    };
    tv.postDelayed(action, 1000);
```

**Solution for dynamic color change:**

```
class HSVSpan extends CharacterStyle {
    int color;
    float[] hsv = {0, 1, 1};

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setColor(color);
    }

    public void update() {
        hsv[0] += 5;
        hsv[0] %= 360;
        color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
//        Log.d(TAG, "update " + Integer.toHexString(color));
    }
}
```

and testing code:

```
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("0123456789");
    final HSVSpan span = new HSVSpan();
    ssb.setSpan(span, 2, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(ssb);
    tv.setTextSize(32);

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            span.update();
            tv.invalidate();
            tv.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    };
    action.run();
```

Comment: have you any sample of that? CharacterStyle is super class of ForegroundColorSpan ... What about Editable, doesn't it cause update to TextView upon changes?

Comment: Thanks for your code but I think you didn't get the point of the question. I have a fixed color and dynamic start and end span positions. The span positions are only changed in each run not the style of the span

Comment: ok so extend ReplacementSpan and create one instance per TextView line, now you can do whatever you want with drawing

Comment: The most efficient solution utilizing underlying SpanWatcher and the rest inner mechanisms of TextView. Thanks.

Comment: SpanWatcher? how can it help? SpanWatcher only notifies about span addition, deletion and change

Comment: So what happened here is a span change. No problem here. Result is very good. :-)

Answer (score 1):

execute below code once:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mainText);
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
```

and every time you want to change span do this:

```
ssb.clearSpans()
ssb.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
tv.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: @vipual, I did it already, looking for any better way than setting the whole text

Comment: is doing this giving you bad performance?? I thing when change happens you need some way to refresh UI.

Comment: None of those are bad actually, I want to minimize the CPU memory load as much as possible. I know the refresh is required but actually only some characters are changed in each run.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin actualy none of them are changed: only the span changes: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue this afternoon,and here is my solution:

```
tv.setText(yourText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
((Spannable) article.getText()).setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I found it's a much more efficient way,in my project I used set-whole-text method took 400~600 milliseconds,by this way only 0 or 1 millisecond.

Comment: More efficient than what?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to modify the spannable held by the textview without calling setText again

Read [this title: Creating custom spans](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) and [this title: Setting text for maximum performance](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/underspanding-spans-1b91008b97e4) from these articles for more information.

```
val spannable = SpannableString("Text is\nspantastic")
val foregroundColor = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED)
spannable.setSpan(
     foregroundColor, 
     /*start*/ 1, 
     /*end*/ 3, 
     SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
)
textView.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE)

GlobalScope.launch{
  // later getting the mutable instance of the text object held 
  // by the TextView
  // this can can be cast to Spannable only because we set it as a
  // BufferType.SPANNABLE before
  val spannableText = textView.text as Spannable
  delay(1000)
  spannableText.setSpan(foregroundColor, 2, 4, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)

  delay(1000)
  spannableText.setSpan(foregroundColor, 3, 5, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
}
```

Note that we only updated the `spannableText` without the need to call `setText()` again, the difference is that setting text again will cause the view to be redrawn and recalculated, while updating the `spannableText` will cause certain methods to be called to update the spans without redrawing the view from zero, and this is the most efficient way to do this.
**ALSO** the key point here is that we are setting the same foreground obejct again and again, this causes the span to move, if we were to create new object each time this wouldn't make the color moving instead will set new color on new places as well as old places.

**In case of changing colors of certain span**

you will need to override `updateDrawState` and set the color, also you will have to call `invalidate()` or `requestLayout()` depending on the change, check “Bonus performance tip” in the second article i mentioned above. here is example for updating link color of URLSpan

```
    class MutableColorURLSpan(url: String) : URLSpan(url) {
        var color = 0

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.color = color
        }
    }

    private fun myTest() {
        val spannable = buildSpannedString {
            append("Hello")
            setSpan(MutableColorURLSpan("https://www.google.com/"), 0, 4, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)

            append(" World")
            setSpan(MutableColorURLSpan("https://www.google.com/"), 5, 10, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)

            append("!")
            setSpan(MutableColorURLSpan("https://www.google.com/"), 11, 12, SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
        }
        binding.textView.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val spannableText = binding.textView.text as Spannable
            delay(1000)
            spannableText.getSpans<MutableColorURLSpan>().forEach { it.color = Color.RED }
            binding.textView.invalidate()

            delay(1000)
            spannableText.getSpans<MutableColorURLSpan>().forEach { it.color = Color.BLUE }
            binding.textView.invalidate()

            delay(1000)
            spannableText.getSpans<MutableColorURLSpan>().forEach { it.color = Color.GREEN }
            binding.textView.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

same applies for other spans, if your requirements is to frequently update certain attribute like color, size, then you will need to inherit the span and store the mutable attribute in the class and set it in `updateDrawState()` or the respective method responsible of setting the attribute.