# underline one word and Bold one word in Textview XML (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, textview

I'm using Android studio text-view to write an small paragraph. I need help with Bold one text and underline that word.

Comment: You cannot do this purely from XML. See `Html.fromHtml()` or use `StyleSpan`s

Comment: Use SpanableString. This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496140/most-efficient-way-for-dynamic-text-color-change-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

You should place the text in string file with u tag and set text style as bold like this...

```
<string name="terms_condition_signup"><u>Please accept the Terms of Conditions</u>.</string>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/terms_condition_signup"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```