# How to use constant & int based string combindly?

Tags: android

My textview -

```
TextView doses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.doses);
```

int getting code -

```
int nIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DOSES);
```

What I want is add some pre defined TEXT like "**DOSE:**" before `nIndex`.
My expected result will be like-

```
doses.setText(cursor.getString("DOSE"+nIndex));
```

How to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
doses.setText("DOSE" + cursor.getString(nIndex));
```

Comment: Great! If i want to add some color like DOSE will be yellow.. how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext