# how can I use StyleSpan for TextView?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I have a TextView in which the text foe an example is: "Android"

Now, I have to change the text style for first 3 char is "And" and except are in normal format.

I follow this SO link for the solution : **[Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)**

**In which Typeface is using through below format and it is working fine**

```
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
```

but

I need to access the style / Typeface from Assets folder like: Parisienne-Regular.ttf

**How can I pass the Assets file into this StyleSpan programatically ?**

---

**Edit 1;**

```
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
```

I found from this **- [link](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) -** but when I applied

```
tnew.setText(Html.fromHtml(" And"+"<font face='Parisienne'>"+ "a"+ "</font>"));
```

also not working.

---

**Ans:**

```
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Parisienne-Regular.ttf");
SS.setSpan (new CustomTypeFaceSpan("", font1), 3, 4,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tnew.setText(SS);
```

And this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass the Assets file into this StyleSpan programatically ?

You don't. Instead, you need a different span class, one that is aware of your custom font. There are a few implementations of this floating around, including some on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819049/how-can-i-use-typefacespan-or-stylespan-with-a-custom-typeface).

Comment: I'll check the link which you provide but I have seen your link http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html , there is <font face= ""> tag . Can I use or not for "Parisienne" font family ?

Comment: @AM: No, because `Html.fromHtml()` only knows about the built-in typefaces, because it works with `TypefaceSpan`, which only knows about the built-in typefaces.