# Display of decimal numbers

Tags: android

I've seen some Android apps display decimal numbers where the decimal part has a smaller font, even though they appear to be in a single TextView, like this:

[image]

I was wondering how to make something like that.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext PS: you can change the color or anything you want there. You should google it a bit more.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 7):

Try to set `HTML` string to `TextView`

```
String text = "831<sup>69</sup>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do this in java file:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>" + "<small>" + description + "</small>"));
```

OR

Use [spans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html).

Example:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");

// Span to set text color to some RGB value
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

// Span to make text bold
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

// Set the text color for first 4 characters
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

// make them also bold
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

yourTextView.setText(sb);
```