# How to show message in bold and break line in AlertDialog box Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show message of `AlertDialog` in two separate lines and text in one line in **bold** style and in next line simple text (without any style).

Now If I am performing break line with bold text , lines are break'd but text is not showing bold. Why ? can anyone help me.

Code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    Spanned s1 = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Text in Bold"+ "</b>");
    String s2 = "Normal Text";
    alertDialog.setMessage(s1+ "\n" + s2);
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Use SpannableStringBuilder instead of string, that may help you

Comment: Try this link, it definitely will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you please try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    String s1 = "<b>" + "Text in Bold"+ "</b>";
    String s2 = "Normal Text";
    Spanned strMessage = Html.fromHtml(s1+  "<br>" + s2);
    alertDialog.setMessage(strMessage);
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: it dont works text looks bold but line doesn't breaks

Answer (score 0):

Use \n to break the line.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
String s1 = "<b>" + "Text in Bold"+ "</b>";
String s2 = "Normal Text";
Spanned strMessage = Html.fromHtml(s1+  "\n" + s2);
alertDialog.setMessage(strMessage);
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```