# Highlight in red the text that's beyond the limit of the EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

How can I highlight in red the text that's beyond the limit of the EditText like so:

[image]

For example, I want a 100 character limit. How can I do it?
This is from YouTube app.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "beyond the limit of the EditText" ?
Text that is not inside EditText ??

Comment: @emiraslan number of character limit

Comment: You don't have this problem: you **can't exceed** the maximum specified character limit (if any).

Comment: @Rotwang I know. But, I want to achieve the effect of the screenshot. It's from the YouTube app.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Unbelievable.

Comment: I guess you'll have to use the TextWatcher object in conjunction with some `HTML.fromHtml()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use spannable to paint different part of the text of an EditText:

```
     final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence.toString());
     final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 0, 0));
     //final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // You can make the text bold!
     sb.setSpan(fcs, yourTextLimit, charSequence.toString().length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

reference :[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897412/6514270)

Set an onChanged listener to your EditText and when its text size exceeds the limit, you can use the code above to change the color of text

---

### For Example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test);

        test.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean changed = true;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                int yourTextLimit = 10;
                final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence.toString());

                if (charSequence.toString().length() > yourTextLimit && changed) {
                    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 0, 0));
                    //final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // You can make the text bold!
                    // sb.setSpan(bss, yourTextLimit, charSequence.toString().length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    sb.setSpan(fcs, yourTextLimit, charSequence.toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    sb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(charSequence.toString()), 0, charSequence.toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    changed = false;
                    test.setText(sb);
                } else if (changed) {
                    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                    sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, charSequence.toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    sb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(charSequence.toString()), 0, charSequence.toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    changed = false;
                    test.setText(sb);
                }

                test.setSelection(charSequence.toString().length());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                changed = true;
            }
        });

    }

    class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {// extend ClickableSpan

        String clicked;
        public MyClickableSpan(String string) {
            super();
            clicked = string;
        }

        public void onClick(View tv) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,clicked , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
            ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, I want a 100 character limit. How can I do it?

Comment: Sorry for being late, a bit busy day ))
Please, consider upvote and accept as an answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: It's not exactly the effect in the image. Look, you'll understand: https://media.giphy.com/media/3oKIPsXGbTSaZjfs40/giphy.gif

Comment: @Programmer  Please, check it again. I have updated it

Comment: I can't click the space bar

Comment: Hmm, wierd .... It doesn't work in emulator keyboard, but it does in real android phone (At least in my phone)